# Angular2 pipe items undefined during page load

Tags: angular

Applying the below custom pipe to filter an array of items:

```
import {Injectable, Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filterHeaders',
  pure: false
})
@Injectable()
export class FilterHeadersPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], args: any[]): any {
    return items.filter(definitions => definitions.isHidden);
  }
}
```

And in my template I just filter on the collection (elided for brevity):

```
  <thead class="table-inverse">
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let item of (items.columnHeaders | filterHeaders)">
        <span>{{item.headerName}}</span>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
```

My component, on `ngOnInit` gets the data that includes the headers:

```
export class TableComponent {
  items: any = [];

  constructor(private service: DataService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getData()
      .subscribe((data: any) => this.items = data);
  }
}
```

However, when I load the page the `items.filter` returns an error since `items` is still undefined. Is there something else I should be doing in my component to make sure the pipe has the items when it runs?

Answer (score 3):

You can put a ngIf on your table to assure it's only shown when the items are defined:

```
<thead class="table-inverse" *ngIf="items">
<tr>
  <th *ngFor="let item of (items.columnHeaders | filterHeaders)">
    <span>{{item.headerName}}</span>
  </th>
</tr>
```

Comment: Just tried that. That just doesn't display the header at all :(

Comment: Might be best to put it on the table (my bad for the wrong code example). If you log out your items by just adding {{items}} to your template, does that show anything once your page is loaded.

Comment: Interestingly, I did put it on the table. The header doesn't show, but the items in the table do with the `ngFor`...